# How to reject false alarm in object detection using SSD?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, caffe2

I used [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) for my object detection. But there are some false detection from some other objects in the image.
That is happening consistently from same objects. So is there a way to reject those components in training?

Answer (score -2):

For Yolo, I can do as follow.
Just add images with these non-labeled objects to the training dataset and train. Network will learn not to detect such objects.

Also it is desirable to add negative-samples to your training dataset: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet
desirable that our training dataset include images with non-labeled objects that we do not want to detect - negative samples without bounded box (empty .txt files). [(Credit to  alexbe)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/darknet/ycEoZA9VvfY/qWtmP7URAQAJ;context-place=forum/darknet)

In general, what we can do are
`Hard negative mining, Inspect confusion matrix and Data Augmentation`.